# How do I map urls to views in Django, getting AttributeError: module 'myproject.views' has no attribute

Tags: python, django

I just started learning django and running the tutorial part 3, decided to see if I understood  the mapping from urls.py to views.py.

I got views and urls to work in the polls app, but then I wanted to make views in the project folder, so I made a views.py file in the project folder (see code below), with a view/function , which I named 'home'.

I then edited the urls.py in the project-folder(see below). run the server, It worked! visiting the url: http://localhost:8000/
it responded:
Hello, world. You're at the HOME PAGE.

BUT.. when I tried to make another view in same views.py called: morn, and adding the url for it, then error (see below), 
http://localhost:8000/morn
returning: 
localhost refused to connect.

I DID IT EXACTLY THE SAME WAY, so just when I thought I understood it, I didnt get it at all?!?!
The difference between the two views are just their name and path, why doesnt it work then?

on a linux manjaro
Python 3.8.1 
Django 3.0.3

#

```
#this is my urls.py (which I made myself), in the project folder

from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
#from views import morn

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    #lager en index-side
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('morn/', views.morn, name='morn'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),

]
```

#

```
#this is the views.py in myproject folder, same folder as 

from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    output = 'Hello, world. You\'re at the HOME PAGE.'
    return HttpResponse(output)

def morn(request):
    output = 'Hello, world. Youre at the morn-path.'
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

ERROR from konsole running the morn-view:

```
File "/home/nr1/dev/django/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 29, in <module>
    path('morn/', views.morn, name='morn'),
AttributeError: module 'myproject.views' has no attribute 'morn'
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh no... I just got it! :)
I have put the views.py file in both of the myproject-folders and the urls.py is just in the inner myproject-folder. I was then updating just the outer views.py-file, when I thought I was in the inner views.py, so, ofcourse, the urls.py couldnt find the new function, it was searching the wrong views.py (outer one).

a lot of frustration for nothing.. but I learnt, I learnt!